# How to know cmap compatible with font in Itext?

Tags: pdf, itext

I check my font's encoding (the font's type is OpenType Font), the result is below :

```
PostScript name: HiraKakuProN-W3
Available code pages:
encoding[0] = 1252 Latin 1
encoding[1] = 1251 Cyrillic
encoding[2] = 1253 Greek
encoding[3] = 932 JIS/Japan
```

Then, creat font by code :

```
Font f = new Font(BaseFont.createFont("hirafont.otf", "Identity-V", BaseFont.EMBEDDED));
```

Except "Identity-V" and "Identity-H", i can't use other cmaps such as ("UniJISX0213-UTF32-H/V ..."). 
And in this font i see many glyphs which is displayed in rotation of 90 degrees. How to map char in unicode to char's glyph which is rotation in font?

Example : '〔 '   (0x3014    12308   LEFT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET) map with index 9265 in font

---------update code--------

```
PdfEncodings.loadCmap("UniJISX0213-UTF32-V", PdfEncodings.CRLF_CID_NEWLINE);
String temp = "a";

byte[] text = temp.getBytes("Shift_JIS");
String cid = PdfEncodings.convertCmap("UniJISX0213-UTF32-V", text);
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("hiraginoFont.otf",BaseFont.IDENTITY_V, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph(cid, new Font(bf, 14));
```

Comment: Could you share a PDF using that font, the code you used to create it, and indicate which glyphs are wrongly rendered?

Comment: I updated code above. Pleas support me to check it.

Comment: Looking at that code I admit that I have not yet needed to dive into those details. Bruno may know his way around. But you already accepted his answer. Thus, if there still are problems, you should probably ask a new question and describe the remaining problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to dig into my first book to find a reference to what you're asking. A long time ago, we used to distribute the following jar: **itext-asiancmaps.jar**.
This jar is not to be confused with itext-asian.jar which is used for CJK fonts.

It took me a while to find a copy of that jar. You'll find it in this old ZIP file: [extrajars-2.1.zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/files/extrajars/extrajars-2.1.zip)

According to my first book (written in 2005-2006), you can use this jar for encodings that are not supported by the CMaps in itext-asian.jar

It is used like this:

```
PdfEncodings.loadCmap("GBK2K-H", PdfEncodings.CRLF_CID_NEWLINE);
byte[] text = my_GB_encoded_text;
String cid = PdfEncodings.convertCmap("GBK2K-H", text);
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("STSong-Light",
    BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph(cid, new Font(bf, 14));
document.add(p);
```

As you know `BaseFont.IDENTITY_H` and `BaseFont.IDENTITY_V` are the horizontal and vertical identity mappings for 2-byte CIDs. The `PdfEncodings` class can convert a `String` in a specific encoding to a `String` with 2-byte CIDs. In this case, the original `String` was encoded in the GB 18030-2000; we needed to convert this to another `String` so that iText could use the `IDENTITY_H` encoding.

In my first book, I wrote: *"I insert this sample for the sake of completeness. In the past three years, only a handful of people have posted questions about this."* By the time I wrote my second book (2009-2010), nobody was asking about this functionality, so I dropped distributing the jar with the cmaps and the example didn't make the second book.

I am now reviving this old example in the hope that it is useful. I tested it once in 2005 or 2006, and it worked back then. I can't guarantee that it still works today.

Comment: thanks for your support. But in itext 5.x up, the PdfEncoding class was modified (loadCmap function and convertCmap function is not supported ). Could you suggest new solutions for this ?

Comment: Well, as iText is an open source library with an open repository, you can always retrieve the history of the code: http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/5019/tree//trunk/itext/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfEncodings.java?diff=4784 The methods you need were removed because nobody used them, but you can still retrieve them: http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/4784/tree/trunk/itext/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfEncodings.java

Comment: Thank for your reply. I want ask about "my_GB_encoded_text". How to convert utf-8 string to GBK2K-H string. sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: i also update my code above. Please support me to correct it .